How to select non-manifold edges in geometry nodes?
I have a piece of clothing geometry that has arm and leg holes, I would like to create a selection of these parts programmatically in geometry nodes, is their an elegant way to accomplish this or am I stuck using vertex groups?

Define "non-manifold edges". You can easily select edges with edge neighbors not equal to 2.

Edges with *Face neighbors != 2 I think is what you mean sir? @MarkusvonBroady

Edge Neighbors Node -> Face Count -> Not Equal 2, specifically. I feel like I always struggle remembering how to access certain geo too. :D I wish it was a little easier in GN foreal.

If you need to select the hole edges, I found workaround here  and here is the blender artist thread.


